# SQL basic Rank function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can someone explain what's wrong with this query?

```
select 
    ename,
    dense_rank() over (order by sal) as r 
from 
    emp
where 
    r = 2
```

I tried to find 2nd largest salary in emp table, please let know what's wrong in that SQL statement.

Also suggest any other methods to find largest rank if possible, thank you!

Comment: Please also add "input data", "output data", and "expected output". currently the SQL statement look OK, but it is unclear why this question is asked because expectation are unclear.

Comment: Please, next time, copy the complete error message (in TEXT) and add that to your question.

Comment: `where` clause is evaluated before projection (select list), so select list expressions are not available in the context of `where` clause

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to use a column alias in a where clause. Wrap the query in a CTE (common table expression - using the "with" clause) and select from that to get the row where rank is 2.

```
WITH ranked_results (ename, r) AS
(
select ename,dense_rank() over (order by sal) from emp 
)
select * from ranked_results where r = 2;
```

this works too:

```
select *
from   (select ename,
               dense_rank() over (order by sal) as r
          from emp )
where  r = 2;
```